# What tag should be used for Hearthstone: Heroes of WarCraft?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today Blizzard announced [*Hearthstone: Heroes of WarCraft*](http://battle.net/hearthstone/) a new collectible card game. The full length title with dashes exceeds the tag length maximum of twenty-five characters. For now I've created a tag of simply [hearthstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearthstone), but am wondering if there are other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no issue with simply using [hearthstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearthstone). The subtitle is not being used to differentiate the game from another title in any way, so it shouldn't be needed at this time.